# Who are the Macbeth Singers? (Double Double Toil and Trouble)?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, character-identification

**Who are the students** in Flitwick's choir in *Prisoner of Azkaban* who are singing the Macbeth song ("Double Double Toil and Trouble")?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, don't have a clearer screenshot ATM. Anyone who has one, would be grateful for improvement.

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Frog_Choir

Comment: Per (the old) [Pottermore](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:CMSKBAom56AJ:https://thefanswholived.wordpress.com/tag/celestina-warbeck/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk) - "Mrs Warbeck reluctantly consented to her daughter’s enrolment at Hogwarts, but subsequently bombarded the school with urging the creation of a choir, theatre club and dancing class to showcase [Celestina's] talents."

Comment: While I admit that my answer is somewhat disappointing, I don't think there's any extra info that can be added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### In-Universe

The only characters known (or strongly suspected) to be in the [Frog Choir](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Frog_Choir#cite_note-PM-0) are

- **[Bem](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Bem)** (named in the *script and closed captions* but not actually named in the book or film credits)
- **[Celestina Warbeck](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:CMSKBAom56AJ:https://thefanswholived.wordpress.com/tag/celestina-warbeck/%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk)** (Named on the old Pottermore site as having been deeply interested in the school's choir. Note that it's not explicitly stated that she was in said choir)

Beyond that, the members are simply listed on the wiki page as "[Unnamed players](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Unidentified_Choir_Member_(II))".

---

### Out of universe

The choir members were actually students of the London Oratory School's all-boy ["Schola" choir](http://www.imdb.com/company/co0105516/), who also provided the actual singing.

Several (presumably non-singing) female extras appear to have been scattered in amongst them to make the choir look unisex.

Comment: So none of them were actual actors shown otherwise to be Hogwarts students elsewhere in the movie or credited?

Comment: @DVK FYI Ekow Quartey played Bem in the films :)

Comment: @DVK - The student known as Bem appeared in both the choir *and* as a student in a later film. The line he speaks in the film is attributed in the book to the student Bem.

Comment: Where does a student called Bem come up in the book?

Comment: @user13267 - It's decidedly convoluted. There's a discussion [here](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Bem) about whether the fact that his line in the book is credited in the closed-caption as "Bem: " is sufficient to name him in subsequent films. I err on the side of yes. He is also named in the [screenplay](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Harry-Potter-and-the-Prisoner-of-Azkaban.html)

Answer (score 2):

I was in the Harry Potter choir. My name is Charlotte Finlay Tribe and I am holding the frog at front with long curly hair. The whole cast of the Harry Potter choir was casted from The Sylvia Young Theatre School.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Could you [edit] in some evidence this is true though? I’m not saying you’re not telling the truth but we have no way of knowing it is true so it would help if there is something in it to back it up.

Comment: This answer also seems to contradict multiple sources which have the (male) singers from the London Oratory School's all-boy "Schola" choir. Were you alongside them or are you saying that these other sources are inaccurate?

Answer (score 1):

The people in the film (myself included) are casted from the Sylvia Young Theatre School but they used choir boys for the vocals.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You (or someone using the same name) appear to have already answered this a few years back.  Please don't post duplicate answers.

Comment: Are you the same Charlotte Finlay tribe who posted [this prior answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/237173/122024) in 2020, using a different account with the same name? If so, we'd appreciate it if you'd take the time to merge your new account with the old one by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). This would enable you to edit this added info into your first answer, rather than posting it as a separate answer.